# Generating random strings based on user input

Tags: python

I am a complete beginner in Python and I want to generate a random string based on user input for a password generator I currently have the below:

```
import random
import string

print("Password Generator")


def lower(length):
    lower_case = string.ascii_lowercase
    generate = ''.join(random.choice(lower_case) for i in range(length))


amount_of_characters = input("How many characters do you want?")
```

I want the input of the user to equal the length of the random string.

For example if the user inputted 36 the string generated is 36 characters long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
import string

print("Password Generator")


def gen(length):
    lower_case = string.ascii_lowercase
    generate = ''.join(random.choice(lower_case) for i in range(length))
    return generate


amount_of_characters = int(input("How many characters do you want?"))
print(gen(amount_of_characters))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

Note: you have to return the final value from your function.
You also have to convert the user input to an int, because all user input starts as strings. (converting user input to an int could give an error if they enter a non-integer like 'asd', which would require exception handling.)

```py
import random
import string

print("Password Generator")


def lower(length):
    lower_case = string.ascii_lowercase
    generate = ''.join(random.choice(lower_case) for i in range(length))
    return generate


amount_of_characters = int(input("How many characters do you want?"))

print(lower(amount_of_characters))
```